# OpenLDAP doesn't return DN

Tags: openldap

our OpenLDAP installation does not return DN attribute in answers to queries. It is listed (and contains correct value) on the "Internal Attributes" page in phpldapadmin, but doesn't appear when I do queries or use some directory browser like jxplorer.
Is it a configuration issue?

Comment: What you seem to be describing is highly unlikely. Please show an example of the output you are receiving.

Comment: You are right. ldapsearch gave me dn... Seems to be problem of the software we try to use. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem of the software. Simle test via `ldapsearch` from cli showed that `dn` is returned.